# prover9 - finding all the possible solutions

Tags: theorem-proving

I'm new to Prover9 and I can't figure out how to extract more than one answer.

Here's my code:

```
assign(max_proofs, 1000).

formulas(sos).

p(a).

p(b).

p(c).

-q(y) #answer(y).

end_of_list.
```

I'd like to get 3 answers (x=a, x=b, x=c), but I only get one.

How do I do this?

Thanks for your help!